# Manually upload file to server

Tags: magento2, php

I need to upload file to Magento manually (without submitting form) - just set path to file in code and upload it to media directory.

I was thinking if doing it via UploaderFactory like this:

```
$uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'datafile']);
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);

$imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
$uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
$mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
$config = $this->config;
$result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($config->getBaseTmpMediaPath()));
```

but it requires $_FILES array.

Is there a way to do it without $_FILES or set it manually?